# logical operator not working in php

Tags: php

I have a php function that returns true or false and works fine when I say:

```
if (is_valid_locale($locale)) {
// do something
}
```

Yet, when I am trying to find something that does not return a valid locale with this:

```
if (!is_valid_locale($locale)) {
// do something else
}
```

When I echo out the function, it does spit out "f" for false. So the function works.

I tried other things such as:

```
if (is_valid_locale($locale)==false) {
// do something else
}
```

However it still did not catch.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `echo false` will *not* print an *'"f" for false'*. It sounds like your function is actually returning the string `"f"` instead of the boolean `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function returns `f`, it doesn't return a boolean value.

As per convention, a function call `is_something()` should return a boolean value, so you should fix the function `is_valid_locale()` to return a boolean instead of trying to cope with what it's returning.

As soon as you've fixed that, your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `===` ,try this:

```
if (is_valid_locale($locale)===false) {
// do something else
}
```

Or if when you echo out the function, it does spit out "f" for false. Then try this:

```
if (is_valid_locale($locale)==='f') {
// do something else
}
```

Comment: Right. `===` return true if `$var1` is equal to `$var2`, and **they are of the same type**.

Answer (score 0):

If echoing the functions result gives you 'f' instead of nothing, you should change it to == 'f'.
Anyway, check what is the type of function result by using

```
gettype(is_valid_locale($locale))
```

Answer (score 0):

In php `False` is equivalent to `0` not `'f'`. Recheck you functions code or try.

```
if (is_valid_locale($locale)=='f') {
// do something else
}
```

Comment: If `false` mean `0`, why you used `if(condition=='f') {}` ?

Comment: Because function is spiting 'f' ..

Comment: Then it isn't true: _In php False is equivalent to `0` not `'f'`._